# Positioning issue using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a hard time to accomplished this: [CODEPEN LINK](http://codepen.io/Unknownymous/pen/alvLG/)

As you can see in my `CODEPEN` sample. As you hover the image it shows the `IMAGE CAPTION` then if you clicked the image it will show the `ACTIVATED IMAGE`(RED BORDERS). My problem is how can I show the `CAPTION` when that image is `ACTIVATED`. I use JQUERY on clicking the image to show  the `RED BORDERS` when activated.

**UPDATE:**
 What I'm trying to do is when its activated it also show the CAPTION onclick just like the RED BORDERS.

Your help is so much appreciated.

Comment: you can do this: when your click function runs add a class to caption that class say the caption "display:block"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS

```
.aboutus .thumb_caption,.leadership .thumb_caption{left: 0;
opacity: 1;}
```

after doing so the caption should be seen on activated.

Comment: Thanks! that's what I'm expecting for.

Answer (score 1):

just need a css

```
.aboutus 
.thumb_caption,
.leadership .thumb_caption{
 left: 0;
 opacity: 1;
  }
```

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ftjmE)